# Multiple selects in an SQL Server stored procedure called inside .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, stored-procedures

I have a working SQL Server stored procedure executed in .NET Core that yields some results.

The procedure is called in this way:

```
var point = new SqlParameter("postCodePointBinary", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500) { Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationIdString) ? (object)DBNull.Value : locationIdString };
var radius = new SqlParameter("radius", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float) { Value = filters.Radius };

var properties = _context.PropertiesInstance.GetPropertiesProcedure.FromSqlInterpolated($"spGetProperties {radius}, {point}").ToList();
```

Inside the `PropertiesInstance` which is the DB context, the procedure is defined:

```
public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Property> GetPropertiesProcedure { get; set; }
```

Property is a simple object with 4 attributes:

```
public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the SQL Server stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetProperties] 
    @radius float,
    @point nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @radian float = @radius * 1609.34
    DECLARE @postCodePoint geography = geography::STGeomFromText(@point, 4326)
    
    SELECT 
        p.Id, p.Latitude, p.Longitude
    FROM 
        Property p
    WHERE
        p.Active = 1
        AND geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326).STDistance(@postCodePoint) <= @radian
END
```

This works fine, and the variable properties has a list of the results from the stored procedure. I now need to expand the procedure, so that it has 2 selects, and retrieves 2 tables.

The new stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetProperties] 
    @radius float,
    @point nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @radian float = @radius * 1609.34
    DECLARE @postCodePoint geography = geography::STGeomFromText(@point, 4326)
    
    SELECT
        p.Id, p.Latitude, p.Longitude
    FROM
        Property p
    WHERE
        p.Active = 1
        AND geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326).STDistance(@postCodePoint) <= @radian
    
    SELECT Id, Url
    FROM Media
    WHERE PropertyId IN (SELECT Id FROM Property)
END
```

If I execute the .NET code, the list of properties is still there, but I'm unsure how to get the 2nd table. An initial idea I had was using a new DTO in the `dbContext`, that would contain the old Property object, and a new object for the 2nd select (with Id and URL) but apparently that's not the way to go.

```
public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<**NewDto**> GetPropertiesProcedure { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure about the EF code but that second query I would use an inner join instead of IN with a subquery.

Comment: Maybe see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets

Comment: Multiple result sets is not a supported feature. Though there is this old hack that .... probably doesn't work https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127#issuecomment-330973013

Comment: EF Core Power Tools combined with Dapper supports multiple result set mapping